# .htaccess redirect loop when trying to add forced HTTPS rule (Amazon Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I started receiving this error after trying to incorporate a rule to force HTTPS in the production environment.  The BWC_ENV environment variable can have a handful of different values: "prod", "stage", "ben_local", "nam_local", etc.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:BWC_ENV} ^prod$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in our scripts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?subdomain=%1

# Ditto for the path; map all requests to /index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA] 

# robots.txt - supply the correct one for each environment
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /robots.prod.txt [NC] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:BWC_ENV} !prod
RewriteRule ^robots.prod.txt$ /robots.stage.txt [NC]
```

---

## Edit

What's more, if my .htaccess only contains the following, this will cause a redirect loop too.  Why could this be?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turns out this is an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer thing.  You have to use Amazon's `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to accomplish this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I have a site hosted on [NearlyFreeSpeech](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/) and I needed to use `X-Forwarded-Proto` to get this to work, too.  I also had a redirect loop with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `L` flag missing in few rules. Type changing your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:BWC_ENV} ^prod$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in our scripts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]

# Ditto for the path; map all requests to /index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA] 

# robots.txt - supply the correct one for each environment
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /robots.prod.txt [L,NC] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:BWC_ENV} !prod
RewriteRule ^robots.prod.txt$ /robots.stage.txt [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors in my rules @anubhava.  The cause of the problem was actually Amazon's elastic load balancers, but your pointers were helpful for other reasons!